# Including Multiple Attachments In Transaction Kills Node

Tags: corda

**Setup**

- Corda 4.6
- Working from Java template

I have been experimenting adding up to 10 Attachments of small (1K) zip files to a transaction.

**Error when testing with StartedMockNodes:**

```
io.github.classgraph.ClassGraphException: Uncaught exception during scan
    at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraphException.newClassGraphException(ClassGraphException.java:89) ~[classgraph-4.8.90.jar:4.8.90]
    at io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1555) ~[classgraph-4.8.90.jar:4.8.90]
...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.NestedJarHandler.readAllBytesWithSpilloverToDisk(NestedJarHandler.java:815) ~[classgraph-4.8.90.jar:4.8.90]
    at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.PhysicalZipFile.<init>(PhysicalZipFile.java:161) ~[classgraph-4.8.90.jar:4.8.90]
    at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.NestedJarHandler.downloadJarFromURL(NestedJarHandler.java:576) ~[classgraph-4.8.90.jar:4.8.90]
...
```

**Error when testing local nodes built with CordForm and connecting with RPC:**

Node will stop suddenly.  No errors in the log.  In the directory of the failed node there will be two files:

- hs_err_pid20400.log
- java_pid20400.hprof

log file has similar errors as StartedMockNode failures:

```
j  nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.NestedJarHandler.readAllBytesWithSpilloverToDisk(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/String;JLnonapi/io/github/classgraph/utils/LogNode;)Lnonapi/io/github/classgraph/fileslice/Slice;+65
j  nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.PhysicalZipFile.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;JLjava/lang/String;Lnonapi/io/github/classgraph/fastzipfilereader/NestedJarHandler;Lnonapi/io/github/classgraph/utils/LogNode;)V+25
j  nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.NestedJarHandler.downloadJarFromURL(Ljava/lang/String;Lnonapi/io/github/classgraph/utils/LogNode;)Lnonapi/io/github/classgraph/fastzipfilereader/PhysicalZipFile;+428
j  nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.NestedJarHandler.access$000(Lnonapi/io/github/classgraph/fastzipfilereader/NestedJarHandler;Ljava/lang/String;Lnonapi/io/github/classgraph/utils/LogNode;)Lnonapi/io/github/classgraph/fastzipfilereader/PhysicalZipFile;+3
j  nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.NestedJarHandler$4.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;Lnonapi/io/github/classgraph/utils/LogNode;)Ljava/util/Map$Entry;+124
```

Clarification #1: The error occurs during transaction execution.  Not when originally uploading the files to the node using `CordaRPCOps.uploadAttachmentWithMetadata` (that works fine).

Clarification #2: The first node to fail is the one constructing the transaction.  If you try restarting this node it will fail on restart.  It will take several re-starts to get up and running again.  Then any node that was receiving the transaction will fail.  They will also require several restarts to get up an running again.  As a testament to Corda's Flow framework - after enough restarts the transaction will eventually be successful and the Attachment's will be transmitted.

Clarification #3: I can pre-upload the Attachments to all the nodes before executing the transaction and the failures still occur.

Answer (score 0):

**StartedMockNodes:**

Found [this](https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/6495)

Added the following to my workFlows build.gradle file to stop the errors:

```
test {
    maxHeapSize = "4096m"
}
```

**Local Nodes & RPC:**

??? - haven't found a solution yet